# yeoman generator-material-app: not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, frontend, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I started estudr the yeoman and testing a generator equipment-app (https://github.com/michaelkrone/generator-material-app) I came across a problem. When performing APPLICATION, get umo following error in the browser console:

```
TypeError: cssClasses.split is not a function
    at jqLiteAddClass (angular.js:2897)
    at Function.$get.extend.addClass (angular.js:3538)
    at angular-animate.js:119
    at forEach (angular.js:336)
    at $$addClass (angular-animate.js:118)
    at options (angular-animate.js:132)
    at close (angular-animate.js:2328)
    at queueAnimation (angular-animate.js:2156)
    at Object.$$AnimateQueueProvider.$get.push (angular-animate.js:2053)
    at Object.$AnimateProvider.$get.leave (angular.js:5224)
```

I identified that the angle is coming a function in cssClasses parameter rather than a string as follows:

```
cssClasses = (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
2893
  if (cssClasses && element.setAttribute) {
2894
    var existingClasses = (' ' + (element.getAttribute('class') || '') + ' ')
```

I have done: npm install, install bower and gulp build but none of that helped a lot.
Anyone know anything I can do to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually quite simple.  There is a problem with jqlite, then we can install the full jquery in front of angularjs.

As AngularJS documentation states, if jquery is loaded before AngularJS script, jquery will be used instead of jqlite.

Since the problem is in jqlite, so if we use jquery instead of jqlite, the problem goes away.

All you need to do is:

```
$ bower install --save jquery
```

and then add the following line before angular.js script loading:

```
<script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

And this problem should goes away.